# Php session refresh to see user's settings change

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, session

I've got an issue, I've looked everywhere and can't find an answer.
On one of my pages I have it set so users can change there firstname/lastname etc, once the change is done, they can't see there firstname change, the only way they can at the moment is to logout then login again.
I've tried session refresh, but that doesn't help, although it does change the session ID.
If someone could link me a tutorial or even post a snippet of code that does that, it would be great! Thank you. My current script for displaying the user's data is via session.

```html
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR);

?>

<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["user"]) or !is_array($_SESSION["user"]) or 

empty($_SESSION["user"])

)


// redirect to index page if not superuser

header('Location: index.php');

mkdir('users/'.$_SESSION["user"]["id"])

?>

<?php

$old_sessionid = session_id();

session_regenerate_id();

$new_sessionid = session_id();

echo "Old Session: $old_sessionid<br />";

echo "New Session: $new_sessionid<br />";

print_r($_SESSION);

?>

<h3 align="left"><?= $_SESSION["user"]["firstname"]  ?></h3>

<h3 align="left"><?= $_SESSION["user"]["id"]  ?></h3>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What's your current ([MCVE](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve)) code that handles name display and settings? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: If you store the usery new name in the session (for example $_SESSION['firstName']) and display the sessions content on the web page it should be automatically updated each time the html page loads new. I guess you have a logical problem in your code.

Comment: Well, the firstname is stored in the Database, once a user is logged in, it gets there ID and generates the session ID. And from there it gets all the details from the database.

Comment: We need some more information: Where is the displayed data comming from? Session or database? And where do you write the change to? Database or session? Because I guess you are displaying the database but only updating the session. Or - you are displaying the sessions value but writing the change to the databases and loading the values from database only once by logging in. So the changed value is stored in database but not renewed in the session as well.

Comment: I just realised once you said that, that it's storing it in the database, but retrieving it from the session. Although is there a way I could refresh the session once someones updated the data and its been updated to the database. Because it's not storing it in the session. But fetching it from the session, in a way.